# How to use two digits of number after zero in System Dynamics in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

[image]

As you can see in the above image, the Land Availability Value is currently 0.999. This result is messing up my table function, my table function is as follows

[image]

As you can see if the value is 1 or 100% then the value should be 0, but in my case in the first image you can 0.999 is being treated as 0.9.

How to overcome this problem i.e. treat 0.99 as 1?

Comment: what kind of interpolation are you using?

Comment: I am using Spline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do is the following for your land availability variable assuming that the formula you have now is

```
tableFunction(businessStructure)
```

you can do

```
businessStructure>0.99 ? 0 : tableFunction(businessStructure)
```